# Depth of primary and secondary minimum in a light curve

Tags: data-analysis, binary-star, light-curve

How can I explain approximately the same depth of primary and secondary minimum in light curve?

I observe star HD 36486. I tried filters MOST and BRITE.

Is it related with photometric filter? When I change the filter in program for analysis the result is the same.

Comment: Which object are you observing, what filters are you using?

Comment: I observe star HD 36486. I tried filters MOST and BRITE.

Comment: If the two stars are very similar...

Comment: They are not similar, their radia differ about 8 radia of Sun and their mass differ about 9 mass of Sun

Comment: Please add all relevant information to your question.

Comment: Can I contact you in some way?